# libvlcsharp controls Fonts not found ie Icons like play pause fast forward(IOS)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I created a project i am using libvlcsharp with xamarin forms project in android controls are seen but in IOS i see Question marks instead of control icons please help me out i have included all font files as well any lead will be helpful

my ui code

```
            <vlc:MediaPlayerElement MediaPlayer="{Binding MediaPlayer}"

                                    IsVisible="{Binding ContainsUrl}"
                                    LibVLC="{Binding LibVLC}">
                 <vlc:MediaPlayerElement.PlaybackControls>
                     <vlc:PlaybackControls IsAudioTracksSelectionButtonVisible="False" IsClosedCaptionsSelectionButtonVisible="False" IsAspectRatioButtonVisible="False" ShowAndHideAutomatically="False">

                     </vlc:PlaybackControls>
                 </vlc:MediaPlayerElement.PlaybackControls>
            </vlc:MediaPlayerElement>
```

Comment: Please check your csproj file. Lines like these must be present : https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp/blob/77dee2c7e7602f511dc0b080e18391525210095f/samples/Forms/LibVLCSharp.Forms.MediaElement/LibVLCSharp.Forms.MediaElement.Sample.iOS/LibVLCSharp.Forms.MediaElement.Sample.iOS.csproj#L99

Comment: Also, the code you pasted isn't relevant since it works on Android. There must be something wrong in your project. If you want help, please post a sample project on github or similar platform. Be sure to compare it with https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp/tree/3.x/samples/Forms/LibVLCSharp.Forms.MediaElement

Comment: It’s probably because you added the icon for play and pause in your android project and not in your iOS project. What tutorial are you following?

Comment: Actually i did a silly mistake libvlcsharp is using font awesome and i added it to my project but missed to add it in my info.plist due to which fonts were not loaded